# java options issue when launching Tomcat

Tags: tomcat9

I have a problem with running a Tomcat 9. When I start my application, I get the following error message  NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED and when HTTP Status 404
Please tell me how to solve this problem. Where and how should I add these options?

I am using Windows 10. Development environment - intellij idea